# Object Lifecycle Management questions

Tags: google-cloud-storage, lifecycle

This post refers to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

A warning states:

```
It is recommended that you test your lifecycle policy on development data before applying to production, and observe the expiration time metadata to ensure your policy has the effect you intend.
```

This is good advice, but Google Cloud Storage makes it difficult to follow.
There can be a lag between when the conditions are satisfied and when the action is taken.
So the workaround is to observe the Expiration Time Metadata instead.
But "The Expiration Time Metadata" section says:

```
the expiration time will not be available for the object if:
* The NumberOfNewerVersions condition is also specified
```

Referring to the example "Deleting live objects after 30 days, and keeping only the 3 most recent versions of each object in a bucket with versioning enabled."
After what event are the Live objects deleted in 30 days?
Is there a way to test the example?